# Multiple input fields using same class taking first value on POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form, this form (to keep a long story short) has the same input field multiple times (could be anywhere from 2-5 times). The form has to have this field multiple times, there is a reason behind why it's there several times.  I use to have the input field using an ID, but had to change it to a class because of the fact that the field is going to be there multiple times.

```
<input type="text" style="width: 231px; height: 25px;" name="myname" class="myclass" placeholder="myname">
```

I am then using ajax to post the data to a database.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/myfile.php",
       data: {"myname": $(".myclass").val()},
```

When the second field is POSTed, it's always null, however the first POST works just fine.  Any thoughts on what I can do to make this work, knowing I MUST have this field on the page multiple times?

**UPDATE:**
 
I want the two fields to post individually, not at one time because I want them to be different records in a DB. So what happens is, I post the first time, click save and then the second instance of the field appears (using jquery), upon clicking save of the second field set, the page should post again.

Answer (score 0):

`val()` only returns the value of the first element in the collection, if you want all of them you have to map them into an array

```
var values = $.map($(".myclass"), function(el) {
     return el.value;
});

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/myfile.php",
   data: {"myname": values},
});
```

If it's a form, you could also use [`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [`serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) to do the same.

Comment: I want them to post individually, not at one time because I want them to be different records in a DB.  So what happens is, I post the first time, click save and then the second instance of the field appears (using jquery), upon clicking save of the second field set, the page should post again.  Would your solution work in that instance?

Comment: @user2828701 - If you're going to send different values when the user does different things, you have to figure out what values to send when? You should minimize requests to the server, so it makes no sense to loop over the values and send a request for each value unless the sending happens at different times? If that's what you're considering doing, reconsider, send them all at once, and sort them out on the serverside before creating the different records for your DB.